# How can I translate html files using python and google translate

Tags: python, html, google-translate, translate, scrape

I am trying to translate a web page (I have to do it using python and google translate). I already downloaded the content of the page using httrack. For purposes of summarizing the problem, suppose for now I want to translate only the "index.html" file.
I have tried the following:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import codecs

with codecs.open('index.html', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])

translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest='hi').text

with codecs.open('index_translate.html', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(translated_text)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diegol/Documents/scraping_class_central/traduccion.py", line 12, in <module>
    translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest='hi').text
  File "/home/diegol/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 219, in translate
    parsed = json.loads(data[0][2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

What should I correct?

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation for `translator.translate`, in order to understand what should be passed?

Comment: I certainly haven't. I already realized that I am missing the src parameter.